# Is this a strange use of the past perfect tense?

Tags: past-tense

More stories and news in the music press kept coming from Ireland about a new band called U2, formerly known as The Hype, so a decision was made to change the band name to The Action.

Robbie lived near a 'Mod’ clothes shop shop with the same name. Nobody in the band at that time had referenced the sixties band of the same name! DOH!

Robbie lived near a 'Mod’ clothes shop shop with the same name. Nobody in the band *at that time* **had referenced** the sixties band of the same name! DOH!

I don't understand very well this sentence

Normally the past perfect verb should occur before the one in past simple . So we could understand this sentence like this .Nobody had referenced the sixties band of the same name before Robbie lived near a"Mod" cloth shop with the same name . In that case it would be crystal clear.

What confused me is " at that  time".This expression  means when Robbie lived near the shop not before. So both events happened at the same time and both were not completed  at that time. So why past perfect for reference "
My question is:" before what hadn't the band referenced the sixties band"

Comment: You don't tell us the context, but I'm guessing that, some time ago, Robbie gave his band a name copied from that of a local shop. At that time, none of them realised that there had already been a band with the same name in the 1960s.

Comment: [I don't understand this sentence very well]. "had referenced" occurs *before* he lived there. It does occur before the one in the simple past, it is just stated in the next sentence...

Comment: so why at that time in this case means before he lived near the cloth shop  of the same name

Comment: I think  I got it "at that time" means just after they had  changed their name into "the Action"

Comment: It's absolutely fine. "At that time" is describing a time in the past, but using the past perfect tells us about actions which occurred before and up until "that time".

Comment: so at that time means  before Robbie lived near the cloth shop  before they realised that they had been a band with the same name. I find it strange that at that time means before something

Comment: No.  At that time just means at a previously mentioned time in the past.  When you use the past perfect after "that time", then  that is what changes the time frame to something that happened before and up until "that time".

Comment: thanks it is clear now

Comment: I think the cited text is badly phrased, and thus not worthy of too much attention. In particular, I doubt anyone could convince me that ***referenced*** is a sound choice of verb here. It's someone trying to sound more "literary, eloquent" than they really are, and in consequence making a fool of themselves.

Comment: Here's [a little diagram](https://imgur.com/liIhalN) that might help you visualize the time frame.  I agree with @FumnleFingers that the verb **referenced** is a bit strange here. But we can't see all of the context, so it might be fine, hard to tell.

Comment: yes pretty clear

Comment: It's a **clothes** (garment) shop, not a **cloth** (fabric) shop!